# trying to add condition inside grid view but it's give me an error

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

trying to add condition inside grid view but it's give me an error that cannot simplicity convert type object to bool I want if the v_flag = c then return v_amount else return 0 and this my html but not working

```
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="credit">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="v_amount" runat="server" Text='<%# ((Eval("v_flag")) = "c" ) ? Eval("v_amount"): "0.00"   %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use equality comparison operator `==` instead of assignment operator `=` The condition must be evaluated to boolead i.e. `true` or `false`, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

*Change*

```
Text='<%# ((Eval("v_flag")) = "c" ) ? Eval("v_amount"): "0.00"   %>'
```

*To*

```
Text='<%# ((Eval("v_flag")) == "c" ) ? Eval("v_amount"): "0.00"   %>'
```